# Checking if an element is present in an associative array

Tags: linux, bash

I have an associative array like that

```
Array=(["one"]=1 ["two"]=2)
```

and after a bit of googling to find if "one" is in the array keys, I found that

```
if [ ${Array["one"]+_} ]; then echo "Found"; else echo "Not Found"; fi
```

It works as I want but I don't understand the `+_` right after `Array["one"]` What its meaning?

Comment: This is explained in detail at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value -- the point of replacing the original value in this use case is that `_` is guaranteed not to be empty, and it's also guaranteed not to word-split into multiple separate words (in which case it could be an invalid argument list for `[` and thus cause an error rather than evaluating to true when used unquoted).

Comment: oh thanks this cleared thing for me